# Unable to apply Bootstrap or React-Bootstrap styles to app created with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

As the title says, I followed the installation steps as per the Bootstrap and React-Bootstrap docs after using `create-react-app`:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
```

Then included a link to the bootstrap CDN in index.html just in case:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Here is the very beginning of my react app which does not apply the styles properly:

MyNavbar.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class MyNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Navbar>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="#"> grood </a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Navbar.Header>
                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#"> For Eateries </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyNavbar;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MyNavbar from './MyNavbar.jsx'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <MyNavbar />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Both MyNavbar and App are in the same src file

Comment: Could you post the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) is build for Bootstrap **3** - not **4**.

Install package bootstrap 3 into your project and import css from there.

There is a project for React & Bootstrap 4 though: [reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. 
Do you know if reactstrap is inferior to react-bootstrap in any way?

Comment: I haven't use reactstrap as Bootstrap 4 is alpha and not an option for production yet.

Comment: How do you add a CDN link as described above to a react app?  I'm also trying to following the directions on the react-bootstrap.github.io site, but I'm not sure how to include the CDN in my create-react-app based project?